# Should SQL query's ORDER BY columns be written in the JS code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm paging some SQL queries results in my application with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, now I'd like to add Javascript controls to order the resulting list all the way from the front end to the SQL query's `ORDER BY`.

Where should I write the column to sort by that will be passed to the SQL's `ORDER BY`?

Should it be written in the JS code? Should generic string be passed to the server and then, converted to the SQL's column names?

---

Here are some pieces of code to clarify the problem:

The SQL query to get the rows displayed in the JS:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY :criteria
LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset
```

The JS code responsible for the AJAX query:

```js
function sortBy(selected) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/super/link/to/controller/method?orderBy=" + selected.val(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function (data) {
            // Code here doing the list refresh with the data
        }
    });
}
```

The parameter under `orderBy` will be added to the SQL query with the name `criteria`. It can be manipulated by the server to match the SQL table column's name but is it really a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything inherently wrong with this. There might be other/better options based on different ORM solutions you might be using, but given the information you have provided this solution looks fine as long as you are securing your application against SQL injection.

Comment: Well I don't like the idea of JS writing SQL queries. But yeah I can block it by switching on the value entered in my controller to prevent gibberish being passed to the query. But what I more specifically don't like about it, is that the DB design is affecting JS. It sounds like a pretty stretched design dependency to me.

Comment: I don't see where the query itself is being written in JS. I just see JS passing the selected value in the UI. Like you said, use a switch statement on the server to handle the values coming from the UI and build the query appropriately. At that point the UI is just telling the server what has been selected, and is really not being affected by the DB design at all. The string in the UI doesn't have to be the exact string used in the query, but you do have to have a translation layer to correctly build the query using the string from the UI.

Comment: "you do have to have a translation layer", yeah ok, that's the important part I was looking for. I'll put it in the DAO, right?

Comment: I would need to know much more about your architecture to tell you exactly where to put that. If you are using an MVC pattern I would put the conversion of UI values to database values in the controller.

Comment: We are using the MVC pattern indeed. I'll discuss it internally considering your pov, many thanks.